# How to ammend a condition in helm charts

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Currently, I am checking if lifecycle hooks are **enabled**, if yes add some extra delay:

```
{{- $delay := hasKey .Values "shutdownDelay" | ternary .Values.shutdownDelay 30 }}
{{- $graceperiod := hasKey .Values.service "terminationGracePeriodSeconds" | ternary .Values.service.terminationGracePeriodSeconds 120 }}
{{- $extraDelay := .Values.lifecycleHooks.enabled | ternary $delay 0 }}
terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {{ add $graceperiod $extraDelay }}
```

I want to cover a use case where the if `.Values.lifecycleHooks.postStart` and `.Values.lifecycleHooks.prestart` have some values then it should not add the extra delay in `terminationGracePeriodSeconds`

The `values.yaml` looks like

```
#shutdownDelay: 40
lifecycleHooks:
  enabled: true
  postStart:
    exec:
      command:
        - echo
        - "Run after starting container"
  preStop:
    exec:
      command:
        - echo
        - "Run before stopping container"

service:
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 120
```

So if the poststop hook value is defined like in values.yaml then it should not add any delay to terminationperiod.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very specific but if you are looking for "if"
condition with "and"/"or", below is an example might be helpfull.

As per your explanation assuming value for poststart/prestart, If the lifecycle.poststart is "false" and lifecycle.prestart is "true" then the terminationgraceperiodseconds wont have extradelay else condition will have an extradelay

```
{{- if and (eq .Values.lifecycleHooks.postStart "false") (eq .Values.lifecycleHooks.prestart "true")) }}
terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {{ $graceperiod }}
{{- else}}
terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {{ add $graceperiod $extraDelay }}
{{- end }}

conditional or
{{- if or (eq .Values.lifecycleHooks.postStart "false") (eq .Values.lifecycleHooks.prestart "true")) }}
terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {{ add $graceperiod $extraDelay }}
{{- end }}
```

Comment: I have updated my qyestion with sample values.yaml. Can you have a look